# Prisma client won't run on Raspbian 64 bit

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, prisma, arm64

As I understand Prisma should have binaries which support Raspbian 64 bit. However whenever I try to run any Prisma commands (`npx prisma db push` for example) I still get

`%Error: Not Found https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/d6e67a83f971b175a593ccc12e15c4a757f93ffe/linux-arm-openssl-1.1.x/prisma-fmt.gz`

If I run `uname -m` it returns `aarch64`.

Comment: This is an `HTTP 404` issue. This has nothing to do with binaries or CPU architectures.

Comment: Yes so that means the binary which it targets to is incorrect? I could find a [arm64](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#binarytargets-options) binary but even when I try to set it specifically in `schema.prisma` with `binaryTargets = ["linux-arm64-openssl-1.1.x"]` it seems to default to `linux-arm-openssl-1.1.x`